# QSharedPointer, переданный в лямбда-функцию не уничтожается

Tags: c++, qt, указатели, лямбда-выражение

Есть код примерно такого вида:

```
 QSharedPointer <QFutureWatcher<Data>> watcher (new QFutureWatcher <Data>()) ;

 auto callBack = [=]() mutable {
     // тут действия с watcher
 };

 callAsyncQuery (watcher, callBack);
```

В данном коде я создаю лямбда-функцию, которая копирует `QSharedPointer`, а затем этот указатель и сама лямбда передаются в функцию, которая выполняет некоторые операции в другом потоке и по окончании вызывает эту самую лямбду.
Суть в том, что если написать так:

```
auto callBack = [=]() mutable {
    // тут действия с watcher
};
```

то `QSharedPointer`, судя по всему не сбрасывает счётчик ссылок, и данные, на которые он указывал, не удаляются. Однако если написать вот так:

```
auto callBack = [=]() mutable {
    // тут действия с watcher
    watcher.clear();
};
```

То всё окей и память освобождается... В чём дело - не пойму. Видимо, тут что-то связано с особенностями лямбда-функций.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы выполняете захват **по значению**, т.е. передаете в лямбду **копию** `watcher`. Естественно, никто эту копию не освобождает, это должна делать сама лямбда...

Лямбда, несмотря на то, что она похожа на функцию, на самом деле **объект**, который уничтожается (вместе с захваченными значениями) при выходе из области видимости самой лямбды.

Учтите также, что после выполнения очистки `watcher.clear();` эту же лямбду вызывать нельзя - ее копия `watcher` окажется очищенной.

Вот небольшой пример, демонстрирующий сказанное:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
    int i;
public:
    Test(int i):i(i)            { cout << "Test ctor " << i << endl;    }
    Test(const Test&t):i(t.i+1) { cout << "Test cctor "<< i << endl;    }
    ~Test()                     { cout << "Test dtor " << i << endl;    }
    void doit()                 { cout << "Test doit " << i++ << endl;  }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Test t(0);
    auto l = [=]() mutable { t.doit(); };
    l();
    l();
    cout << "Exit\n";
}
```

Comment: а почему копия указателя не уничтожается при выходе из тела лямбда-функции?

Comment: А что такое лямбда-функция? Это - **ОБЪЕКТ**, а не **ФУНКЦИЯ**, с оператором (), и сохранением захваченных переменных в своих членах данных. Она уничтожается при выходе лямбды из области видимости (тогда же уничтожится и копия вашего `watcher`). Вот, посмотрите на простой пример - http://ideone.com/IkVXdV

Comment: спасибо, тогда последний вопрос. если я,  затем в функции callAsyncQuery делаю QObject::connect(watcher.data(), &QFutureWatcher <ReturnValue>::finished, callBack); То какая тогда у этой лямбды будет видимость?

Comment: Я вообще-то по C++, а не по Qt :) Если лямбда передается по значению - теоретически создается ее копия (что очень вряд ли, ибо тогда она должна исчезнуть при возврате из функции); если по ссылке - что скорее всего - то она существует, пока не выйдет из области там, где объявлена. Но она должна существовать все время, пока не завершится этот асинхронный вызов (как я понимаю, в отдельном потоке).

Comment: Да, но вот в этом то и проблема, все потоки давно закончены,а лямбда не удаляется)